# JS поправить регулярное выражение

Tags: reactjs, регулярные-выражения

у меня есть такая регулярка

```
export const FORBIDDEN_REGEX_TEXTAREA =
  /^(\w+.+\s*:\s*[(ATGCatgc|){}0-9.,+*]+[\s\n]*)+$/;
```

когда я вставляю значения в поле, которые соответствуют этой регулярке, то все хорошо, но как только я допишу туда еще что-то, то страница зависает, методом проб, я понял, что дело именно в регулярке, например если туда положить такую регулярку

```
export const FORBIDDEN_REGEX =
  /\s*(?<name>[^\n\r]+)\s*:\s*[\n\r]*(?<sequence>.*)[\n\r]*/g;
```

то ничего не зависается, мы используем react-hook-form, я кладу регулярку в поле pattern в registerOptions, это вроде стандартная опция из react-hook-form, возможно, моё предположение, регулярка заточена на конкретные символы, а как только я добавляю другие, страница зависает, хотя по идее должна просто выдавать ошибку под полем, кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким, может в регулярке что-то не так прописано?

Comment: В общем, типичный пример catastrophic backtracking, `/^(\w+.+\s*:\s*[(ATGCatgc|){}0-9.,+*]+[\s\n]*)+$/` всё равно что `^(A+B*)+$`. Вам нужно что-то вроде `^\w.+\s*:\s*[(ATGCatgc|){}0-9.,+*]+(?:\s+\w.+\s*:\s*[(ATGCatgc|){}0-9.,+*]+)*$` - я не совсем понимаю, какие символы должен находить шаблон `[\s\n]*`. Если только переносы строк, замените `(?:\s+` на `(?:(?:\r?\n)+` (или `(?:\r?\n`, если разрешён только один перенос).